# Template parse errors: Can't bind to '{ngModel}' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Tags: javascript, html

I did everything about ngModel still i am getting the problem

`Template parse errors: Can't bind to '{ngModel}' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. (" type="text"`

My code:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ServerComponent } from "./server/server.component";
import { ServersComponent } from './servers/servers.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ 
    AppComponent,
    ServerComponent,
    ServersComponent 
  ], 
  imports: [ 
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule 
  ], 
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent] 
})

export class AppModule { }
```

[Example Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u199d.png)

Comment: Please post your code as text to the question

Comment: import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
 import {ServerComponent} from "./server/server.component";
import { ServersComponent } from './servers/servers.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ServerComponent,
    ServersComponent


  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }